# Powershell cmdlet output not shown

Tags: powershell

Consider the script "test.ps1:

```
Get-EventLog -list | gm
```

When it is called from the Powershell console (".\test.ps1"), it outputs the members as expected.

However, the following scripts don't show the output from "Get-EventLog -list | gm":

Script 1

```
Get-EventLog -list | gm
break
```

Script 2

```
Get-EventLog -list | gm

$yes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Yes", "Continua execucao"
$no = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&No", "Cancela operacao"
$options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($yes, $no)
$result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice("Title", "Message", $options, 0)
```

If I change "Get-EventLog -list | gm" to a text like "Hello World", it is correctly displayed, in both cases.

Why is the output from the cmdlet not shown?

Comment: A workaroud is to force the output to host: `Get-EventLog -list | gm
| out-host`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a look on some articles on powershell pipelining. The cmdlet used returns a collection of objects, and powershell's [default behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/redirecting-data-with-out---cmdlets) is to forward the output to the screen.

[This article](http://becomelotr.wordpress.com/2012/04/15/hey-dont-break-my-pipe/) explains that the break statement will break the pipeline (in fact, it will break execution until it finds a parent loop), thus explaining the behavior of the first example.

As for the second example, I assume powershell will only default to redirecting to the console on the end of the script execution. As the $host.ui.PromptForChoice does not use the first cmdlet call's output, and produces it's own, the results from Get-EventLog are just discarded.

As it stands, always using "Out-Host", as @Christian said, is [the way to go](https://web.archive.org/web/20150120044743/http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347728.aspx).